# Run a console application and then close the console and run in background in C++

Tags: c++, background, console

I want to make a console application in C++ and then when the information is displayed, close the console and run in background. Is this possible? Is another way to do that? Python maybe?

Comment: Yes, it this possible!

Comment: What operating system are you targeting? This is not something about the programming language used, but about the environment your program is going to run in.

Comment: @datenwolf i'm programming in windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with a small variant:

- fork another process. But this is heavily system dependent:

  1. [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html)/[linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) allow to simply clone the process;
  2. [windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) requires new process to be created from an executable.  You then have to communicate the state.  Its less trivial [as explained in this article, in the paragraph on porting `fork()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23kc048.aspx))
- then exit the program (it's the only way to give back control to the console).

Comment: Thanks! I gonna see the article

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either close the console window while the process is still running, which is system dependent, or start another process, and even though the standard library offers the `system` function to do that, its argument is a system dependent command line.

So the upshot is: this is system dependent.

In Windows the full-version of Microsoft's Visual Studio IDE has always, as far back as I can remember, used a peculiar approach for this, with two executable files `devenv.com` and `devenv.exe`. The former is a console subsystem executable, which by default runs the latter, which is a GUI subsystem executable:

```
[C:\]
> where devenv
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

[C:\]
> _
```

The basic idea here is that for historical reasons the command interpreter's search for an executable finds the `.com` file first, so the command `devenv` just works, either for starting the IDE or just getting the help text via the `/?` option.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows use `ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false)` to hide the console window. It will still be running in the background  and is not visible on the taskbar.

However you will have to run a task manager like `Taskmgr.exe` to find it and shut it down.

```
#include <windows.h>  
#include <iostream>     
using namespace std;


int main () {   
    cout<<"Some  information is displayed.. \n\n";
    Sleep(5000);

    cout<<"wait.. the console is going to hide and run in background.. \n";
    Sleep(5000);

    ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);

    while(true) {
                 // Do your hidden stuff in here
    }   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code does not work anymore with the new Windows Terminal which can only be minimized but not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers given here overcomplicate things. The most easy way to close the console window in Windows is to simply *detach* from it. Once the last user of a console window datached, the console window gets closed.

If you start a program from a CLI (e.g. cmd.exe) then this CLI is also attaches to to the console and thus the console window will not close.

Anyway, detaching from a console is as simple as calling

```
FreeConsole();
```

… done!

Also you can attach to a newly created console at any time using `AttachConsole`, which takes a process ID. Now in a CLI situation the parent will usually be the CLI shell, so you may want to attach to the console of that.